# Releasing an autoreleased string object doesnt crash

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, autorelease

I have this basic question where when we try to allocate memory to a string by using alloc init and add it to autorelease pool, and then try to release it, it doesn't crash.

```
NSString *value = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"] autorelease]; 
[value release];
```

If I do the same thing for a array, it crashes.
I just want to know how string is different from array since both inherit from NSObject.

Comment: Just a quick side question. Is there any reason you're not using ARC?

Comment: There is no reason. But I am just trying to get a clear understanding of the differences b/w nsstring and other objects.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it doesn't crash right away? 
I.e. in the debugger after stepping over the `release` line?

The Autorelease-Pool will not have triggered at that point so the auto-release operation is still outstanding.

Either way - As always with memory errors they **might not** crash

- *instantly*,
- *on your machine*/*operating system*,
- with this *specific built*,
- with your current *build settings*,
- ...
- or even at all.

It's a programming error nevertheless.

Comment: It never crashes. If I initialize a array and do the same thing, it crashes as soon as it executes the release statement.

Answer (score 2):

It is not guaranteed that the program crashes. Unfortunally there are several errors that does not cause a crash (immediately).

However there is an optimization for string literals. They live eternally regardless of the way they are created, retained or released. `-initWithString:` can be smart enough not to return a new instance of `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

First, undefined behavior is **undefined** -- it is not guaranteed to crash or do any other specific thing. Over-release is undefined behavior.

Second, what is happening here is that string literals evaluate to a pointer to a statically-allocated string object which lives for the lifetime of the program. It is not dynamically-allocated, and thus is not subject to memory management. `retain`, `release`, etc. have no effect on it. `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:...]` (as well as `[... copy]`) on an immutable string object simply retains and returns its argument directly, since there is no need to create a new object. So `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]` is the same as `@"Hello"`.